# Leer e imprimir value de un JSON en pantalla o leer su valué - Angular

Tags: angular

Estoy consumiendo un api la cual me envía un json pequeño con una llave y un valué y al imprimir con `console.log` me muestra el value en consola pero se imprime dos veces no se por que y al mostrar ese valué en un alert al html me muestra como se refleja en el segundo console.log osea asi: `[object Object]`  y solo imprimo una vez.

El json es: `{"message":"Actualizado"}`  mi método es:

```
actualizarUsuario(us: CUsuarioVO) {
    us.id = this.usedita;
    this.servicioUsuario.actualizarUsuarioPersonal(us).subscribe(data => {

      const json = JSON.stringify(data);
      console.log(json); 
      JSON.parse(json, (key, value) => {
        console.log(`value: -> ${value}`); // Imprime esto 2 veces asi: value: -> Actualizado y value: -> [object Object]
        if (value == "Actualizado") {
          this.mensajes("Usuario actualizado", true);
          this.ngOnInit();
        } else {
          this.mensajes(value, false);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

la linea:  `this.mensajes("Usuario actualizado", true);` usa un metodo para enviar un alert al html pero en el mensaje en ves de mostrar actualizado o usuario actualizado muestra es: `[object Object]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` contiene un objeto javascript creado a partir del json recibido, puede usarse directamente:

```
actualizarUsuario(us: CUsuarioVO) {
    us.id = this.usedita;
    this.servicioUsuario.actualizarUsuarioPersonal(us).subscribe((data : any) => {

     if (data.message == "Actualizado") {
          this.mensajes("Usuario actualizado", true);
          this.ngOnInit();
        } else {
          this.mensajes(data.message, false);
        }

    });
  }
```

Comment: en el data.message me da error -> Property 'message' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(2339):

El metodo:
`
actualizarUsuarioPersonal(usuario: CUsuarioVO) {
    return this.http.put(`${this.url}/update/information/Personal`, usuario, { responseType: 'json' });
  } `

Comment: Cierto. Ya actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Funciona perfecto.
Gracias